# Gorm and go-chi REST patch resource

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-chi

I am building a REST API using [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) and [gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/)

I want to have a patch route where I can update only the properties I receive in the request body.

I am not sure how is the best way of passing there properties to [gorm update method](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html).

Which would be a good way of doing so?

Here is the handler method.

```
func (m Env) UpdateHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var delta InsurancePolicy
    insurancePolicy := r.Context().Value("insurancePolicy").(InsurancePolicy)

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&delta)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }


    result := m.DB.Model(&insurancePolicy).Update(delta)

    if result.Error != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    } else {
        err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(insurancePolicy)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }

}
```

It uses this middleware to preload the request:

```
func (m Env) InsurancePolicyCtx(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var insurancePolicy InsurancePolicy
        result := m.DB.First(&insurancePolicy, chi.URLParam(r, "id"))

        if result.Error != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
            return
        }

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "insurancePolicy", insurancePolicy)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get to a solution for this?

Comment: Hello harm . I did, I posted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right Gorm method to use for updating non zero values is [Updates](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns)